# Cant close modal triggered from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am triggering a react-native modal from a parent component, the modal shows up, when I try close the modal with a button in the child component / model itself, nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is in child component

```
state = {
  display: false,
};
```

```
setModalVisible(visible) {
  this.setState({display: visible});
}
```

```
onPress={() => {
  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.display);
}}
```

This is in parent component

```
<DisplayModal display={this.state.display} />
```

```
triggerModal() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
   return {
     display: true
     };
  });
}
```

```
this.triggerModal()
```

Comment: in your triggerModal, you are setting your modal display to always true. that's why nothing is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should negate the modal value to open and close it

```
triggerModal() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
   return {
     display: !prevState.display
     };
  });
}
```

And instead of passing the state to `setModalVisible`, you can just use the callback setState.

```
setModalVisible() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({display: !prevState.display}));
}

onPress={() => {
  this.setModalVisible();
}}
```

## Edit:

You added your code and here is something that might be the problem

```
ADD_DETAILS(index) {
    if (index === 0) {
        console.log("clicked 0");
        this.triggerModal();
        console.log(this.state.display);
    }
}
```

The reason why it doesn't open and closes can be because it doesn't pass that if condition.

## Edit 2:

Now I see your problem, what you need to do is call `triggerModal` in the children.

So here is what you need to do

1. Pass `triggerModal` as props to the children
2. Call it when you want to close the modal.

So here is the change in the parent.

```
<DisplayModal display={this.state.display} triggerModal={this.triggerModal}/>
```

And in the child

```
onPress={() => {
  this.props.triggerModal();
}}
```

Comment: (And also use the same callback syntax in the child component modal event)

Comment: that is the answer @charl

Comment: Modal still does not close if I make the changes mentioned here

Comment: @Charl Please add the complete code of parent and child components

Comment: @Charl Please add it to your question, not as an answer

Comment: It would not allow me to add all the code, but ill try again. 

@Vencovsky the modal does open, it just doesnt close

Comment: @Charl maybe it doesn't closes beucase it doesn't pass that if condition. Please check that and also remove the if condition to see if it closes

Comment: The condition is for a ButtonGroup, to select a button. If I remove it, there is no button to click to open the modal.

Comment: That condition is also not related to closing the modal. The modal is closed in the child component.

Comment: @Charl now I see the problem, please check my edit. You don't need to store the display in the children, only need in the parent and then call the function of the parent to close the modal.

Comment: I removed the condition, it does not make a difference, the modal opens but I cant close it when clicking the button in child component

Comment: undefined is not a function (evaluating
'this.setState(function (prevState){
return {
display: !prevState.display
); 
})')

Comment: @Charl Now this is another problem in your code, you need to change your class methods to arrow functions, this means insteado of `someFunction() {}` it should be `someFunction = () => {}`. You should do that with all class methods.

Comment: @Charl if that worked, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and leave a up vote, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in parent =>

```
state = {
  display: false,
};
```

```
setModalVisible() {
  this.setState({display: !this.state.display});
}
```

```
<DisplayModal handlePress = this.setModalVisible.bind(this) display={this.state.display} />
```

then in child:

```
onPress={() => {
  this.props.handelPress();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached it:

```js
function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(true);

  const closeModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  const activateModal = () => setShowModal(true);

  return showModal ? (
    <DisplayModal closeModal={closeModal} display={showModal} />
  ) : (
    <button onClick={activateModal}>Display modal!</button>
  );
}
```

```js
const DisplayModal = props =>
  props.display ? (
    <>
      <div>Display!!</div>
      <button onClick={props.closeModal}>Hide!</button>
    </>
  ) : null;
```

**Pay no attention to hooks**, just notice the pattern I have used, passing the `closeModal` function as a prop and calling it whenever it is the case, but from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

at first 
inital

```
state ={
  display: false}
```

create function handalepress

```
handalePress=()=>{
this.setState({
display:!this.state.display
}
<DisplayModal onClick= {this.handalePress}display={this.state.display} />
```